# Entity Framework code first foreign key select query issue

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have a POCO which has a foreign key that looks like this

```
public partial class DataFileInformation
{
    public DataFileInformation()
    {
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? HistoryID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLines { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedByPersonnelNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }    
    public virtual JobHistory History { get; set; }
}

public partial class JobHistory
{    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }    
}
```

Mappings:

```
class DataFileUploadInformationEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DataFileInformation>
{
    public DataFileUploadInformationEntityMap ()
    {
        ToTable("DataFileInformationsView");
        HasKey(fileMetaData => fileMetaData.ID);
        HasOptional(file => file.History)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(file => file.HistoryID);
    }
}

public class JobHistoryEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<JobHistory>
{
    public JobHistoryEntityMap()
    {
        ToTable("JobHistoryView");
        HasKey(job => job.ID);
    }
}
```

Even with the configuration the dynamic query getting fired looks like this

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Extent1].[DataFileInformation_ID] AS [DataFileInformation_ID], 
    [Extent1].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedByPersonnelNumber] AS [UpdatedByPersonnelNumber],
    [Extent1].[UpdatedDateTime] AS [UpdatedDateTime],
    [Extent1].[JobID] AS [LoaderJobID],
    [Extent1].[JobHistory_ID] AS [JobHistory_ID],
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1],
    [Extent2].[StartDate] AS [StartDate],
    [Extent2].[EndDate] AS [EndDate],
    [Extent2].[UpdatedByPersonnelNumber] AS [UpdatedByPersonnelNumber1],
    [Extent2].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate],
    FROM   [DataFileInformationsView] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [JobHistoryView] AS [Extent2] 
        ON [Extent1].[LoaderJobID] = [Extent2].[ID] 
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=146
```

The dynamic query getting generated is unable to map the JobHistory_ID and the DataFileInformation_ID to the POCO and EF throws an exception unable to find columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect class name for `DataFileInformation` mapping, and property name for optional foreign key:

```
class FileUploadInformationEntityMap :
    EntityTypeConfiguration<DataFileInformation>
{
    public FileUploadInformationEntityMap()
    {
        ToTable("DataFileUploadInformationEntity");
        HasKey(f => f.ID);
        HasOptional(f => f.History); // here you have LoaderJobHistory
    }
}
```

Also make sure you are looking at correct SQL, because from SQL I see names `DataFileInformationsView` and `JobHistoryView`, but mapping provides table names `DataFileUploadInformationEntity` and `JobHistoryEntity`. And you don't need to specify `HasOptional` - FK will be nullable by default.

---

After you updated your question, your mapping should work. You can also add cascade deletion configuration (but that is not necessary)

```
HasOptional(f => f.History)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.HistoryID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Sorry i had written the the wrong code. I've edited it o show the problem

Comment: I tried removing the FK but it still throws the same exception. Am i missing something else

Comment: @user761728 be careful when writing questions. Now your code works just fine for me. It generates table with `HistoryID (FK, int, null)` column. BTW where are you getting your 'dynamic' query from?